# Header is not being added to specific path NGINX, Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, nginx

Trying to add a no index header to a specific path (/path) but it doesn't show up. When I add it in with the other add_header lines, it shows just fine but not when put into location /path {} or even location / {}. I've read a bunch of answers on the forum and haven't been able to figure out the issue. Anyone know or see what I'm doing wrong? Nginx version is 1.13.3

Here's my nginx file:

```
server {
    listen 443 ssl http2 default_server;
    listen [::]:443 ssl http2 default_server;

    server_name mydomain.com;
    root /home/forge/mydomain.com/public;

    add_header X-Frame-Options "SAMEORIGIN";
    add_header X-XSS-Protection "1; mode=block";
    add_header X-Content-Type-Options "nosniff";
    add_header Referrer-Policy "origin";
    add_header Strict-Transport-Security "max-age=31536000; includeSubdomains; preload";

    index index.html index.htm index.php;

    charset utf-8;

    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$query_string;
    }

    location /path {
        add_header X-Robots-Tag "noindex" always;
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$query_string;
    }

    location = /favicon.ico { access_log off; log_not_found off; }
    location = /robots.txt  { access_log off; log_not_found off; }

    error_page 404 /index.php;

    location ~ \.php$ {

        try_files $uri /index.php =404;
        fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
        fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php/php7.1-fpm.sock;
        fastcgi_index index.php;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        include fastcgi_params;
    }

    location ~ /\.(?!well-known).* {
        deny all;
    }
}
```

Comment: My guess is that the `try_files` in `location /path` passes processing on to your PHP location block, which means the header is not added.  Maybe [this solution helps](https://serverfault.com/questions/928183/add-header-not-working-in-nginx-location)?

Comment: You should place the `add_header` statement at the same level as all of your other `add_header` statements, then use a `map` to control its value based on the `$request_uri`.